# Is it there a property to arrange menu items horizontally in AndEngine?

Tags: andengine, menuitem

Is it there a property to arrange menu items horizontally AndEngine?
The default layout is vertical, do you know a way to set it horizontal?

Comment: I did it before, check [mine](https://github.com/yhuiyang/AndEngine/commit/1d28d00da8c4ca17837da024682b3eaa4eb451e7).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built it functionality that would arrange menu items horizontally, but check the `MenuSceneAnimator` class, especially `getMenuItemX` and `getMenuItemY` methods. It should be pretty easy to implement your own positioning that will suit your needs.

Comment: thanks, that's what I needed to know, will try to make a function that "horizontalizes" the layout of any and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with, I know it can be optimized, but it works.

```
/**
* Sets menu items layout to horizontal 
* @author  Lucas Massuh
* @version 1.0
* @since   2015-05-28
* @return returns the "horizontalised" menu, just in case. 
* @param menu This should be the menu scene containing all the Menu Items to be set horizontal 
* @param padding This is the horizontal padding between each Menu Item
*/  private static MenuScene setMenuLayoutToHorizontal(MenuScene menu, int padding){
    if (menu.getChildCount()<=1) return menu;
    // Starts at 1 since child[0] position won't be changed
    for(int i=1; i<menu.getChildCount();i++){
        menu.getChildByIndex(i).setPosition(
                //it can be optimized by pre-calculating item's width if they are all equal
                menu.getChildByIndex(i-1).getX()+menu.getChildByIndex(i).getWidth()+padding,
                     menu.getChildByIndex(0).getY());
    }
    return menu;

}
```

Comment: Instead of using a static method to fix the layout later, create your own Animator class and override the placement methods. It would me much cleaner.